# c' in mediation analysis

Tags: regression, mediation

I need to test the effect of X on Y through M. Based on knowledge, I know X does not have direct effect on Y. X has to act on Y through some mediator(s). In this case, do I still need to estimate the direct effect of X on Y (c') in my model? Is it ok if I only estimate a (effect of X on M) and b (effect of M on Y), and test if the product of ab is significant?

Answer (score -1):

Most mediation tests require *two* models and you do not clarify which you are referring to. If you use the Baron/Kenny approach, you need two models: X->M and M->Y. If you do the Sobel test, you will fit a model with the marginal effect X->Y as well as the conditional (direct) effect X,M -> Y.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is on the last model "conditional (direct) effect X, M ->Y". Based on my knowledge, if I know X has no way to act on Y directly, can I skip the last model? Is it OK is I only have two models X->M and M->Y?

Comment: @user106506 read and familiarize yourself with [Sobel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_test). You cannot simply constrain the effect to be 0 with 0 standard error, or else everything is a mediator. Baron/Kenny is different.